# Run command on bash output delimited by space

Tags: bash, redhat, scripting

```
~]$packageManager list packages
```

gives back

```
wordA1 wordB1 wordC1
wordA2 wordB2 wordC2
wordA3 wordB3 wordC3
```

I then want to run a second command on all B-column words, e.g.

```
~]$packageManager install packages wordB1 wordB2 wordB3
```

How can I achieve this elegantly, maybe as one liner with xargs..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sudo yum install $(yum list packages | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

Comment: Just an example since you want to get the second column.